# display Each value Count from an array

Tags: c#

I have a `string[]` with values like

```
string[] s = { "saravanan", "Karthick", "Jackson", "saravanan" };
```

I want to see below output

> saravanan occures 2 times
>   Karthick occures 1 times
>   Jackson occures 1 times

How can I do this *without using* `List` or `Dictionary`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
int i, j;
String[] s = {"saravanan", "Karthick", "Jackson", "saravanan"}

Console.WriteLine("Number of Times occured Each Values");

for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
    {
        if (s[i] == (s[j]))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s[i]+"is count="+count);
}
```

That code produces this output:

> Number of Times occured Each Values
>   saravananis count=2
>   Karthickis count=1
>   Jacksonis count=1
>   saravananis count=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want `"saravanan"` to appear twice in your output.  Then you could use an empty string as a sentinel value.  When you find matches that increase the count, blank out that element and have checks in place to skip the element when you run across it later.

```
using System;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] s = { "saravanan","KArthick","Jackson","saravanan" };
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) 
        {
            // Skip empty element
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }

            int count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.Length; j++) 
            {
                // Skip empty element
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s[i]))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (s[i] == s[j])
                {
                    count++;

                    // Clear the element to indicate the element as already been counted
                    s[j] = string.Empty; 
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} occurs {1} times", s[i], count);
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
saravanan occurs 2 times
KArthick occurs 1 times
Jackson occurs 1 times
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yfwd7z)

Answer (score 4):

Usually, we solve such problems (*querying*) via *Linq*

```
  string[] s = new[] { 
    "saravanan", "Karthick", "Jackson", "saravanan" };

  var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(chunk => $"{chunk.Key} occures {chunk.Count()} times"));

  Console.Write(result);
```

In case of *nested loops* (your current code) we should *not* print out the same name *several times*. Let's introduce `bool appeared` if name has been appeared before

```
   string[] s = new[] { 
     "saravanan", "Karthick", "Jackson", "saravanan" };

   for (i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
     int count = 0;
     bool appeared = false;

     for (j = 0; j < s.Length; j++) {
       if (s[i] == (s[j])) {
         // Names are same. Do we have the name before?
         if (j < i) {
           // If yes we have no need to loop any more
           appeared = true;

           break;
         }

         count++;
       }
     }

    // if name has been appeared already we shouldn't print it out 
    if (!appeared) 
      Console.WriteLine(s[i] + "is count=" + count);
  }
```

Comment: Good answer.  So many times on SO people answer questions such as these with LINQ, a technique so inappropriate (and lengthy _dot notation_ has questionable readability for the best of us) for OPs who are obviously new to c# if not programming in general.  So refreshing to see an answer starting with LINQ, but then to show a more useful classical and easier to comprehend implementation.  Well done good sir! +1

Comment: Great! @MickyD i have knowledge of linq thats why i have give answer like that and i know its wroking well but my answer is not for negative voting. I have always prefer short code method. whatever like that.

Comment: @CoolJK your question had `3 downvotes` I believe and had aspects that made it a poor answer that LINQ didn't even come into it.  To suggest that anyone would downvote an answer based purely on technology choice is perhaps unwarranted. I suspect the reasons for down-votes was either code-only answer or that it just didn't work.  I think most of us enjoy _"short code"_ but confusing an already confused OP is not the way to go about it.

Comment: @CoolJK Thanks for Your code. It is very usefull for me and i must go to learn about Linq now.
            var groups = s.GroupBy(v => v);
            foreach (var group in groups)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} occures {1} times", group.Key, group.Count());

Answer (score 2):

you can use linq group option like this:

```
 String[] s = {"saravanan", "Karthick", "Jackson", "saravanan"};

        Console.WriteLine("Number of Times occured Each Values");

        var groupArray = s.GroupBy(x => x);
        foreach (var group in groupArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Key + "is count=" + group.Count());

        }
```

Comment: please check this answer is true tanks.